# Razer naga & ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, mouse

Are there any configurators with profiles for the Razer naga mouse? I've found [this link](http://bues.ch/cms/hacking/razercfg.html), but I don't know how to install it.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, other than that, there is no configurator for Razer devices (other than one that is now quite a bit outdated), and according to Razer, they have no plans to port their Synapse to Linux.
As for installing Razercfg, all the instructions are in the README file, but I guess I can summarize it for you:
The following is required in order to install:

- Python 2.5 or 2.6 (should be installed by default)
- [libusb (1.0<)](http://www.libusb.org/)
- QT4 Python Bindings (`python-qt4` in the Debian/Ubuntu repos)
- CMake  (2.4<) (`cmake` in the Debian/Ubuntu repos)

Extract the archive, then, in terminal, move to the directory you just extracted. Next, type `cmake`, then `make`. After that, you will want to switch to root (`sudo su`) and then type `make install`.
Again I'll say it: all of this is in the README file that comes with razercfg. It's not terribly difficult to follow the instructions in it, but just in case it is, this guide should be a bit easier to follow.

Comment: Sad. May be there any ways to configure naga without gui configurator?

Comment: As far as i can see, no. X seems to think that, when the Naga is switched to the macro key setting (the "123" on the bottom of it), it's just the number row on the keyboard. It's really a pain, since I got a lot of functionality out of the buttons on the side of my Naga.

Answer (score -1):

Thats odd. My mouse seems to switch from the number row to the key pad just fine when I flip the switch. Btw that razer config tool isn't really outdated. Just looks like the dev isn't constantly working on the tool all the time. Sometimes going for a year without an update, but still updating none the less. The last update bing in October last year doesn't seem to old. 
I think the only thing that isn't saving form windows is my dpi settings. I haven't been running this config tool for a while. My death adder just stored the setting internally. My naga doesn't seem to do this. Ill get back to this once I try it out.
Razer's new cloud config software kind of sucks if you ask me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please only write an answer if you really have something helpful to share to solve the original question. Otherwise, please consider gaining more reputation to be able to write comments.